# Microsoft Graph API Shared by me items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm migrating code from OneDrive API to Microsoft Graph API.
In OneDrive, the `/drive/sharedWithMe` and `/drive/shared` endpoints can be used to get the files **shared with** and **shared by** the current user respectively.
In the Graph API I only see the endpoint `/me/drive/sharedWithMe` that is equivalent for the former.
Is there an equivalent endpoint also for the latter or some alternative way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: hi i am facing same problem. have you found any solution for that ?